# Copying sound output to a virtual input

Tags: windows-10, audio, digital-audio

I'm having a very peculiar problem with audio on Windows 10.

I'm trying to copy the output of FL Studio 20 to the input of VB-audio's Virtual Audio Cable - the problem is that I need minimal latency, as I'm playing a guitar and hearing it immediately after it's been run through plugins.

My audio interface (Focusrite Solo 3rd gen) allows for minimal latency and I can hear the output of FL Studio as quickly as I play notes; however, I can't get Virtual Audio Cable to act as an output in FL Studio without using the Asio4ALL driver.

The Asio4ALL driver not only has latency of about 500ms (extremely offputting when playing music) but I can't hear anything except FL Studio when using it.

Is there software similar to VAC that allows me to directly copy audio output **of one program** and use it as an input or some method that allows VAC/VB-Cable to do this?

Note: Stereo Mix seems to have no response, likely because it isn't linked to my audio interface - if that's the solution, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

By the "Virtual Audio Cable" and "VAC", you actually mean VB-Audio's "Virtual Cable" or "VB-Cable" product. The widely known [Virtual Audio Cable (VAC)](https://vac.muzychenko.net) is a different one.

I'm not familiar with FL-Studio, but if it supports ASIO audio interface only, you need an ASIO-to-KS bridge like ASIO4ALL or ASIO2KS to use standard WDM/KS audio drivers.

ASIO4ALL itself does not have 500 ms (or even 100 ms) latency. Its latency is much more less (units of milliseconds), and you can adjust it manually.

As far as I know, VB-Audio offers virtual ASIO interfaces, but I don't know the details.

Comment: "ASIO4ALL itself does not have 500 ms (or even 100 ms) latency. Its latency is much more less (units of milliseconds), and you can adjust it manually."

And yet whenever I use it in FL, the sounds I make are played back about .5 seconds later.

Comment: Definitely, you are doing something wrong. Try to carefully check your signal path.

Comment: I route it from my Focusrite Solo 3rd Gen interface to ASIO4ALL as an input, then from ASIO4ALL to the interface and to VB-Cable as outputs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information about the problem of latency, and also lots of solutions.
Below are some of them that might prove helpful.

Asio4ALL should not have a large latency if configured right.
The most common problem is too large buffering.
For more information about configuring the buffers see the article
[Optimising The Latency Of Your PC Audio Interface](https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/optimising-latency-pc-audio-interface).

If your sound device has true ASIO driver, you can use program AsioConfig to set base latency. This program is available from the
[djDecks website](https://djdecks.be/)
for
[download here](http://www.djdecks.be/asioconfig.exe).
The djDecks site points also to their later software evolution of
[Virtual DJ](https://virtualdj.com/),
free for home use.

Another asioconfig program is available from
[Github](https://github.com/jprjr/asioconfig),
described as "A small program for pulling up ASIO device control panels".

Another tool against latency is
[Cakewalk by BandLab](https://www.bandlab.com/products/cakewalk),
free after registration.

An alternative universal ASIO driver is
[FlexASIO](https://github.com/dechamps/FlexASIO).
See the article
[Low latency audio on a Windows PC with the built-in soundcard](https://josephbasquin.fr/multiclientasio)
for more information.

Comment: @Corsaka: Have you tried any of these products?

Comment: Yeah, sadly it doesn't seem like they're working @harrymc; it seems more like an issue with ASIO interactions and FL Studio. However, I do have a solution, which is to use an external mixer to route everything, which allows me to hear things in realtime, but route it to others with a delay.